# A compounded integer functional equation $f \big(f^2(m) + 2f^2(n)\big) = m^2 + 2 n^2$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, functional-equations

Denote by $S$ the set of all positive integers. Find all functions $f: S \rightarrow S$ such that
$f \big(f(m)^2 + 2f(n)^2\big) = m^2 + 2 n^2$ for all $m,n \in S$.

---

Obviously, the identity function $f(n)=n$ is such a function and I do not know how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: By $f^2(x)$ do you mean $f(f(x))$ or $f(x)^2$? It's never totally certain.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: You are right. I hesitating over the symbol as well. Let us take it as $f(x)^2$ first, then ask the question for $f(f(x))$. I edited the question.

Comment: Quick observations: $f$ must be injective. And on the set of numbers of the form $n^2+2m^2$, it must be bijective

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, I just realized that not long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved on [the Art of Problem Solving High School Olympiad forum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h274322p1484888).